# Mariadb master-slave replication stopped without errors

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication, master-slave

I have setup mariadb master slave replication about a week back.It worked fine for 3-4 days but later the replication has stopped without giving any errors.The value of seconds behind master parameter is increasing.
I have posted the screenshot of

> SHOW SLAVE STATUS;

below for reference.[image]

Below is the result of `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

[image]

Doing `mysqlbinlog mysql-relay-bin.000040 > slave.txt` this is the error i got

```
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Found invalid event in binary log', data_len: 39, event_type: -93
ERROR: Could not read entry at offset 535: Error in log format or read error.
```

How to get the replication to work again?This problem is because of master or slave db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be because of corrupted mysql binary log.I ended up skipping a counter and replication continued from there.Also shifted to row based replication which seems like much safer option than statement based(this has nothing to do with replication stopping).